# My iMac Doesn't boot it. Hangs with spinner and verbose mode can't boot

Tags: macos, imac, startup, performance

I have my iMac and I have to install Yosemite because I got iMac with older version when I got it. Then I did too many updates but I had my iTunes account and I had my credit card option set to "None" so that's where I started. My iMac froze!!! I can't boot anywhere! I haven't plugged any USB devices at any side I can find. So I used my second but it's non-mac computer. "Yes I have PC and iMac" but I gonna online and searched how I can boot to verbose mode "Learned when I got it". And then I hold "Command" key wich is "Windows" key on pc keyboard and I press "V" as well to boot to that mode but then I noticed this error came up.

---

### xc240 -- 0xd000 -- 0xbc00 *****

And i did look in Google but there are no results for the error so i was worried that i should reinstall it. But i hate that because its waste of time. What command can i do in "Single user" mode for bringing OS X back to life?

---

### Specs of my iMac

### - 5024MB Ram = 4.9 GB Ram

### - 150GB of hard drive space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your installation is messed up.

Are you able to boot in Recovery Mode?

Hold both the Command and R keys on the keyboard until you hear the chime noise.

Comment: I know what i did! I just got older mac CD/DVD installation disc burned on my windows pc so now i have mauntain lion and i can upgrade to the latest version